# What is the difference/relationship between extent and allocation unit?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, indexing

Can you explain the difference -or relationship- between 'Extent' and 'Allocation Unit' in SQL?

Comment: You might glean some useful information from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187501.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190969.aspx).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The allocation unit is basically just a set of pages. It can be small (one page) or large (many many pages). It has a metadata entry in [`sys.allocation_units`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189792.aspx). It is tracked by a [IAM chain](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverstorageengine/archive/2006/06/25/646865.aspx). The most common use of allocation units is the 3 well known AUs of a rowset: IN_ROW_DATA, ROW_OVERFLOW and LOB_DATA.

An extent is any 8 consecutive pages that start from a page ID that is divisible by 8. SQL Server IO is performed in an extent aware fashion: *ideally* an entire extent is read in at once, an entire extent is write out at once. This is subject to current state of the buffer pool, for details see [How It Works: Bob Dorr's SQL Server I/O Presentation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2010/03/24/how-it-works-bob-dorr-s-sql-server-i-o-presentation.aspx). Extents are usually allocated together, so all pages of an extent belong to the same allocation unit. But since this would lead to overallocation for small tables a special type of extent is a so called 'mixed' extent, in which each page can belong to a separate allocation unit. For details see [Inside The Storage Engine: GAM, SGAM, PFS and other allocation maps](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/post/Inside-The-Storage-Engine-GAM-SGAM-PFS-and-other-allocation-maps.aspx).

So as you see the concepts are related, but very different. Perhaps you should explain a bit what is the problem you're trying to solve or why are you interested in these concepts, perhaps we can then elaborate.

Comment: In case you are looking for the working links. Here they are: [How It Works: Bob Dorr's SQL Server I/O Presentation](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-support/how-it-works-bob-dorr-s-sql-server-i-o-presentation/ba-p/316031); [Inside The Storage Engine: GAM, SGAM, PFS and other allocation maps](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/inside-the-storage-engine-gam-sgam-pfs-and-other-allocation-maps/)

Answer (score 2):

Each object (be it an index or a heap) has a number of partitions (1-15k). Each partition can have three different allocation units, the HoBT (heap or b-tree, also known as the hobbit) where your actual data is stored. The LOB ALU for the LOB types as well as the SLOB ALU for row-overflow data.

Pages belong to a certain allocation unit. All pages belong to an extent - a group of 8 pages. While the individual pages can belong to different allocation units, they'll always belong to the same object in a uniform extent - while a mixed extent contains pages for different objects and potentially different allocation units.